# How to load a file properly independently on the server?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to know what can I do in order to load a file independently of the server.
Let's say:
on `localhost:8080` everything works perfect but on the production environment I am getting a 404 error on the site `http://by.prodigious.com/flag/`

Error: `GET http://by.prodigious.com/assets/data/usersdata.json 404 (Not Found)`

This is the function I am using to retrieve that data:

```
var loadData = function () {
    USERSDATA = getLocalData();

    if (!USERSDATA) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: location.origin + '/assets/data/usersdata.json',
            dataType: 'json'
        }).done(function (response) {
            console.log('~ Loaded Users Data [Ajax] ~');
            setLocalData(response);
        }).fail(function (jqXHR) {
            console.log('\u26A0 ' + jqXHR);
        });
    }
};
```

On the object I am using `url: location.origin + '/assets/data/usersdata.json'`, what I did was to remove `location.origin` so `url: 'assets/data/usersdata.json'` but now I am getting an error on the console when I do `gulp build`:

```
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/Users/berretan/Documents/Projects/org-chart/dist/assets/data/usersdata.json'
    at Error (native)
```

What do you recommend me to do in order to avoid these errors?

Comment: Gulp really resolves the path of your Ajax call? What do you do, if you make an Ajax call to a servlet without an actual file? Are you sure, you're getting this error by just changing the path in the Ajax call?

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 yes. If I change that path automatically I get that error.